# Debugging Filesystem access

Tags: debugging, logging, filesystems

I'm looking for a Windows tool that is able to log every action (read & write) that were made to a specific path inside the local Filesystem in order to debug a program (find out why it is sometimes slow and sometimes not).
In theory it could work like a virus scanner that is recognizing every file that any of the running programs do read or write and logs every thing that it sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called Process Monitor made by sysinternals http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx which will moniter the filesytem and registy, it will show which process is doing the operations.  It should help you do what you need

I love the applications made by sysinternals, they make the computer world such a better place to work in.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), previously known as [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx).